# unable to install SQL server on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, sql-server-2017, ubuntu-20.04

when i tried to install sql server 2017 it show:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvbK7.png)
mssql-server : Depends: libssl1.0.0 but it is not installable

i need some help

Comment: You are in the wrong site! SO is for programming and not for maintaining PCs.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and this guide from github helped me:

Add 18.04's main repository using ->

```
echo "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bionic.list
```

Update repository cache and check if libssl1.0-dev is now available:

```
sudo apt update
apt-cache policy libssl1.0-dev
```

Install libssl1.0-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev
```

[github link](https://github.com/haiwen/seafile/issues/1735#issuecomment-673346247)